# TSql: Trouble with join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a join query but can't seem to filter it out.  I'm selecting an invoice table and and applied payments table.  I want to get the balance of all invoice totals amount - applied amounts.  I can get the applied amounts fine using sum but when I try to get the total invoice amount, it is too high because its pulling multiple invoice results if more than one payment has been applied to it.

My results:

```
Invoice No | Amount | Paid
----------------------------
      1    |   10   | 5
      1    |   10   | 2
      2    |   50   | 50
```

How do I select the sum invoice amount for unique invoice numbers?.

Query Overview:

```
Select sum(invoiceamount) - sum(appliedamount) as balance
FROM invoice
LEFT JOIN invoicepayments ON invoice.invoiceid = invoicepayments.invoiceid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually looking for a very simple use of GROUP BY. You want to group every result that is the same Invoice/Amount, and then subtract the total (SUM) of the Paid column for that group from the Amount you are grouping on.

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM
(
SELECT invoiceamount - SUM(appliedamount) as balance
FROM invoice
GROUP BY invoiceid, invoiceamount
) balances
```

Comment: The only thing is that I want one value, the balance of all the total invoices - total payments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CTE where you first calculate amount paid on each invoice and than join it to invoices to figure out what is left to pay for each invoice.

```
;WITH   InvoicePay
          AS (
               SELECT invoiceid
                   ,SUM(appliedamount) AS totalpaid
                FROM invoicepayments
                GROUP BY invoiceid
             )
    SELECT i.invoiceID
           ,i.invoiceamount - totalpaid as Balance
        FROM Invoice AS i
        JOIN InvoicePay AS ip
            ON i.invoiceid = ip.invoiceid
```